# Migration Tomcat between OS

Tags: tomcat, logging, operating-system, tomcat6

Apache ver. 6.0.44
Java ver. 1.6

Few days ago I made a migration beetwen OS version (hp-ux -> rhel) and logs of my application has changed

Before:
`{r=39303805 d=20/05/11 08:00:02 p=ERROR t=TP-Processor349} c=pl.xyz.abc.xyz.abc.DetermineProcessorImpl`

Now:
`{r=235946 d=20/12/02 18:08:43 p=DEBUG t=http-123.123.123.-8080-5} c=pl.xyz.abc.xyz.abc.DetermineProcessorImpl`

Why was change this?
t=TP-Processor349 -> t=http-123.123.123.-8080-5

I made a full copy beetwen OS but I have a huge diffrence in application logs. Nothing has changed.
log4j.properties was the same on both OS.

Can you help me with this problem? How to change IP address to thread processor
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you copied everything directly? Or did you maybe upgrade Tomcat as a part of your migration? BTW, you *really* need to upgrade to a supported version of Tomcat.

Comment: Yes, everything was copied between OS. In second step I will upgrade Tomcat version.